# Adding dropdowns to the tinyMCE editor

Tags: php, tinymce

I'm new to php and wordpress but I've managed to figure out both pretty easily thanks to the community, forums and blogs. I'm close to figuring out what i want to do here, but wasted hours without results yesterday, so i figured i'd reach out.

**What i want to do is enable the user to select a block of text including `<ul>`, multiple `<p>` tags and select an item from the tinyMCE editor and wrap that entire block of text in a `<div class="something">... </div>.`**

I've started with this great tutorial, but I think my lack of experience is causing me not to understand it, or I'm walking in circles again. http://alisothegeek.com/2011/05/tinymce-styles-dropdown-wordpress-visual-editor/

I've successfully managed to get this method to wrap each tag in it's own div, so if i have an `<ul>` each `<li>` will be in that class, but that won't work for what i'm attempting to do. I really need to wrap the entire selection in a new div.

Here's my current array item (refer to step 2 of method 2 in the link above):
...

```
>  array(
>               'title' => 'Div Section',
>               'block' => 'div',
>               'classes' => 'newClass',
>               'wrapper' => true
>             ),
```

Thanks for any advice!

**UPDATE**

was asked to include the full array:

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mce_before_init' );

function my_mce_before_init( $settings ) {

    $style_formats = array(
        array(
            'title' => 'Button',
            'selector' => 'a',
            'classes' => 'button'
        ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Callout Box',
            'block' => 'div',
            'classes' => 'callout',
            'wrapper' => true
        ),
        array(
           'title' => 'Div Section',
           'block' => 'div',
           'classes' => 'newClass',
           'wrapper' => true
         ),
        array(
            'title' => 'Bold Red Text',
            'inline' => 'span',
            'styles' => array(
                'color' => '#f00',
                'fontWeight' => 'bold'
            )
        )
    );

    $settings['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );

    return $settings;

}
```

Comment: Ryan, whenever possible, a Question should be self-contained without the need of external information to understand and provide an answer. Can you post your current code?

Comment: I put the relevant code in here already; however, i'll put the rest of the array from the plugin in there now. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I was referring to a complete working sample. The tutorial is one thing, another is the code that you are using. Whomever is interested in answering should be able to simply *copy* the code **here** (not there) and *paste* to test it. ::: Oh, can you specify exactly what is not working? What goes wrong?

Comment: I must have been ambiguous. This is a plugin, put it in your plugins folder, then there's an multidimensional array where you add/alter the items and styles you wish to show up in the tinyMCE editor. The only addition/ change i made was listed in the original post. The result was also mentioned: i can get the code to wrap each item (for instance, each li) in the class, but what i was hoping to do was wrap the entire selection in a div. Since the result is in your wordpress install in the edit post/page section it's a little more than copy/paste...